# Conditional formatting formula error

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I was following the tutorial on [this](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2013/10/29/excel-change-row-background-color/#row-color-another-cell) page to do some conditional formatting, but I'm getting an error when using this formula

> =AND ($B3>=45, $B3<=54)

Error message:

[image]

It says there is a problem with the formula, and it explains if it starts with an = or - sign it means it's a formula...
The information on the error doesn't say anything helpful. Not used to work on excel so sorry if this is stupid. Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: Include error you are getting.

Comment: Does `$B3` have actual numerical data in it?  Please post a reproducible question.

Comment: @Petermonteer is the value in column B numeric?

Comment: Enter `=AND(TRUE, TRUE)` into any cell.  Do you still get an error?

Comment: @CallumDA I took some spaces out and changed to ; and it magically worked, thanks for the suggestion! I'm new here so I don't know how to credit your answer but thanks!

Comment: Still it accepts the formula but I don't see any changes in the color of the cell. I added the other conditions I wanted and the colors also, but no luck.

Comment: @Petermonteer, I would always recommend trying the formula on the worksheet before using it in conditional formatting. Check that it returns `TRUE` where you expect it to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, try changing your comma `,` to a semicolon `;`.

```
=AND($B3>=45; $B3<=54)
```

[As pointed out by IQV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48823752/whats-wrong-with-this-excel-formula/48824230?noredirect=1#comment84652295_48824230), you will also need to use the Portugese version of `AND()` which is `E()`:

```
=E($B3>=45; $B3<=54)
```

Here is a source for translating English functions to Portugese functions:
http://dolf.trieschnigg.nl/excel/index.php?langids=en+po

Your regional settings determine whether you need to use a comma or semicolon as a separator. So, when you find formulas with commas in future you'll need to make the same changes again.

You could also change your *list separator* in your control panel. Go to *Clock, Language and Region > Region and Language > Additional settings > List separator* and change it from `;` to `,`.

For more details, see here: 
http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/why-your-version-of-excel-only-accept-semicolons-in-formulas-instead-of-commas/.

Comment: I was not aware that regional settings influenced Excel syntax.  Most programming languages do not have this +1.

Comment: But it's strange, that the localized function name should not work. It would be interesting, if localized function name `E()` and `;` would work too. In german Excel one can use `UND()` in conditional formatting.

Comment: @IQV, I thought that was much more likely to be the problem as well. Perhaps Excel allows local language and English?

Comment: @CallumDA I tried it out. In german version it doesn't work. Only german function names work. It's surprising and strange...

Comment: You were right! When changing to ; it accepted the formula but it didn't work, I had to change to E() so it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Obviously you use a localized excel. So in conditional formatting you have to use the localized function names. When using `E()` instead of `AND()` it should work.

And as CallumDA mentioned in the comments you should prove which list separator you have to use in your formulas: `;` or `,`.